# Error compiling openni2_camera -> libopenni2_wrapper.so

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, openni2-camera, openni2, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'am trying to get openNi2_camera with ros hydro running on a raspberry pi. The other files just went fine, now the executeable is failing with the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target openni2_camera_node
[ 92%] Building CXX object openni2_camera/CMakeFiles/openni2_camera_node.dir/ros/openni2_camera_node.cpp.o
/tmp/ccU7U6HY.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccU7U6HY.s:82: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for this architecture
Linking CXX executable /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/openni2_camera/openni2_camera_node
/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniStreamRegisterNewFrameCallback'
/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniStreamGetProperty'
/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniDeviceIsCommandSupported'
/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniDeviceSetProperty'
```

I couldn't use `apt-get install libopenni2-dev`, which is why I compiled everything from the source, having working Sample-Apps of OpenNi2 like SimpleRead.

I also added something to the CMakeLists.txt like that:

```
set(PC_OPENNI2_LIBRARIES /home/pi/OpenNI2/)
include_directories(${PC_OPENNI2_LIBRARIES}/Include)
include_directories(${PC_OPENNI2_LIBRARIES}/Source)
```

Thanks for any advice in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163366/error-compiling-openni2_camera--%3E-libopenni2_wrapper.so/) by [honky](https://answers.ros.org/users/15546/honky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After adding this to my CMakeLists.txt it worked:

```
include_directories(/home/pi/kalectro/OpenNI2/Include)
include_directories(/home/pi/kalektro/OpenNI2/Source)

##Find pack for OpenNI2
find_path(OpenNI2_INCLUDEDIR
      NAMES OpenNI.h
      HINTS /home/pi/kalectro/OpenNI2/Include)
find_library(OpenNI2_LIBRARIES
     NAMES OpenNI2 DummyDevice OniFile PS1090
     HINTS /usr/lib/ /usr/lib/OpenNI2/Drivers
     PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
message (STATUS ${OpenNI2_LIBRARIES})
include_directories(${OpenNI2_INCLUDEDIR})
link_directories(${OPENNI2_DIR}/Redist)
include_directories(${OPENNI2_DIR}/Include)
```

---

Originally posted by [honky](https://answers.ros.org/users/15546/honky/) with karma: 51 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0